# how to get a path of my working folder in php?

Tags: php, path, document-root

i am new in php.
here i have given my project structure and my working folder name is 'Bookings'.

```
   -Bookings
        +Class
        +lib
        -Public
            -application
               +controller
               +css
               +images
        +frontend
```

when i used $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] like this :

```
$path =  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
 echo $path;
```

so obtain output is

```
D:/xampp/htdocs
```

so how to get this path "D:/xampp/htdocs/Bookings" in php?

Thanks

Comment: When people answer your questions, you should use the arrows to the left of their answer to vote it up if it is helpful.  If you end up using a particular answer, there is a checkmark that you can click to accept the answer.  It's an easy way to pay someone back for taking the time to help you...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
define('ROOT', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR));
```

you can use

```
__FILE__
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);` to get your current directory for your existing file.

Comment: Perfect! This is the only solution that delivers the proper server path. All others outputs on windows xampp windows style path which is usually not what we really want.

Answer (score 0):

With

```
__DIR__
```

( http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php )

Answer (score 0):

If you want from the same file you can use this function.

```
dirname(__FILE__)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
   $dir =  realpath('./');
   echo $dir;
```

This should get the absolute path of the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the absolute path with this:

```
$dirpath=realpath(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
echo getcwd();
```

Should also do the trick.

That's where the script starts. You may want to add directories upon it.

Comment: Tested and this won't work because this returns the local file path, i.e. `file://`, and xampp will log an error: `Not allowed to load local resource`